# Using gleffects and v4l2sink in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to use gleffects with v4l2sink in gstreamer, here is my current cli command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glupload !  gleffects effect=5 !  gldownload ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10
```

For some reason I'm getting this kind of error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

while this one works well:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glupload !  gleffects effect=5 !  gldownload ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

I appreciate any suggestions :/

Comment: I've checked and /dev/video10 is fine, I can stream to it when not using gleffects and opengl stuff at all like this:


gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer myself ;) videoconvert seems not to work with v4l2sink out-of-the-box so I had to put a capsfilter element in between so now the command looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! glupload ! gleffects effect=5 ! gldownload ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10
```

Cheers :)